# Selecting Top 25 States By Zip Code using SQL Query

Tags: sql, pyspark, google-colaboratory

I am trying to select the top 25 states with the highest number of zip codes within the state by writing a SQL Query on pyspark. I keep getting an error

> ParseException: mismatched input '30' expecting {, ';'}(line 1, pos 11)

How can I find the top 25 states by number of zip codes? Listed below is the code I tried to use.

```
data = sqlContext.sql("SELECT TOP 25 States * FROM Zip")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . This sounds like aggregation and `limit`:

```
select state, count(*) as num_zips
from zip
group by state
order by count(*) desc
limit 25;
```

Note that you don't have to include the `count(*)` in the result set.  It just seems like a handy value.

Comment: I have to use sqlContext.sql in the coding.

Comment: @IsabellaKnightly what is stopping you from including this sql string into your `sqlContext.sql` object ?